# Bounding Boxes for Keras Applications MobileNetV2 missing?

Tags: tensorflow, object, keras, detection, tensorflow-ssd

I'm very new to Object Detection, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to get bounding boxes from Keras Applications on MobileNetV2: https://keras.io/applications/#mobilenetv2

The model works great in predicting the image content, however the prediction of the model does not include bounding boxes. I'm using the provided Keras example of ResNet50 but changed it to MobileNetV2 as I need the lightweight SSD architecture.

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet')

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = model.predict(x)
# decode the results into a list of tuples (class, description, probability)
# (one such list for each sample in the batch)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
# Predicted: [(u'n02504013', u'Indian_elephant', 0.82658225), (u'n01871265', u'tusker', 0.1122357), (u'n02504458', u'African_elephant', 0.061040461)]
```

I have used a low-level tensorflow implementation of MobileNetV2 and there

```
# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
```

returns bounding boxes. Is Keras missing this or am I going crazy??
Thanks alot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

MobileNetV2 is not an object detection model, it is a classification model, which **can** be used as a trunk network for an object detector, but the base network does not have any object detection capabilities.

You would need to use an object detection framework like the TensorFlow Object Detection API or Detectron.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to the right direction of how to use mobilenet in keras as trunk for object detection?